# Diccionario principal no debería eliminarse

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios

**Tengo unos diccionarios que se anidan de esta manera, el objetivo es reemplazar un diccionario sin eliminar sus otros diccionarios anidados.**

```
Yo ---> soy ---> Lola ---> que ---> tal
           \---> Maria --> hola
```

**La función que veremos mas abajo funciona muy bien en parte, reemplaza Lola por Carlos**

```
Yo ---> soy ---> Carlos--> que ---> tal
           \---> Maria --> hola
```

Dejando intacto los sub diccionarios que estaban en Lola sin embargo aquí viene el problema.
Si se intenta hacer el reemplazo del diccionario o Clave (Yo) todo el diccionario se borra, incluyendo obviamente los sub diccionario quedando todo vacío.

**Esta es la función que remplaza un diccionario**

```
def aprender_con_reemplazo(oracion, buscar):
  recordar_pal = sobre_ti
  for palabra in oracion.split():
      if buscar in recordar_pal:
        recordar_pal[palabra] = recordar_pal[buscar]  # <--- Añadido esto
        del recordar_pal[buscar]
      if palabra not in recordar_pal:
         recordar_pal[palabra] = {}
      recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]
```

Demo:

```
sobre_ti={}
aprender("Yo soy Lola que tal")
aprender("Yo soy Maria hola")
aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo soy Carlos", "Lola")
print(sobre_ti)
Resultado:

{'Yo': {'soy': {'Maria': {'hola': {}}, 
                'Carlos': {'que': {'tal': {}}}}}
}
```

**Intenta reemplazando (Yo)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### El verdadero problema

El problema ocurre en este caso no porque la palabra sea la primera del árbol, sino porque la palabra que quieres reemplazar ("Yo") coincide con la palabra que vas a poner en su lugar (también "Yo").

Mira un ejemplo en el que esto no es así, y funciona bien:

```
sobre_ti={}
aprender("Yo soy Lola que tal")
aprender("Yo soy Maria hola")
aprender_con_reemplazo("Aqui estoy yo", "Yo")
print(sobre_ti)
```

Resultado:

```
{'Aqui': {'estoy': {'yo': {}},
          'soy': {'Carlos': {'Lopez': {}, 'que': {'tal': {}}},
                  'Lola': {'que': {'tal': {}}},
                  'Maria': {'hola': {}}}}}
```

Puedes ver cómo en este caso el "Yo" de arriba del árbol ha sido sustituido por "Aqui", y el resto del árbol se ha preservado. Además se ha añadido una nueva rama por debajo de "Aqui", con "estoy yo".

El problema, como indiqué, no es con la raiz del árbol sino con el hecho de que la palabra que intentas cambiar coincide con la nueva. Por ejemplo, pasaría lo mismo en cualquier otra rama del árbol si quieres cambiar "Lola" por "Lola". Se perdería el resto de esa rama. Mira:

```
sobre_ti={}
aprender("Yo soy Lola aprendiendo python")
aprender("Yo soy Lola en Stack Overflow")
aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo soy Lola experimentando", "Lola")
pprint(sobre_ti)
```

Sale:

```
{'Yo': {'soy': {'Lola': {'experimentando': {}}}}}
```

### ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Debido al siguiente par de líneas tras el `if`:

```
      if buscar in recordar_pal:
        recordar_pal[palabra] = recordar_pal[buscar]
        del recordar_pal[buscar]
```

Cuando encuentra `"Lola"` en un nivel del árbol, se cumple el `if`. Entonces entra y lo primero que hace es copiar la antigua rama que había bajo "Lola" en una nueva entrada. Cuando esa entrada era "Carlos", todo iba bien, pues se crea una entrada nueva y después la de "Lola" se elimina con el `del`. Pero cuando `palabra` es igual a `buscar` la línea que intenta crear una entrada nueva, no crea nada nuevo en realidad, pues esa entrada ya existía. En este caso hará simplemente `recordar_pal["Lola"] = recordar_pal["Lola"]`. Y debido a que después se hace un `del recordar_pal["Lola"]` esa rama se elimina.

Ese era el bug.

## Solución

En realidad cuando la palabra a sustituir coincide con la palabra sustituta, no debe hacerse nada, sino añadir el resto de la frase como una nueva rama bajo esa palabra. Eso es lo que hacía de todas formas la función `aprender()`. Por tanto basta mejorar la condición del `if` para evitar que haga la "sustitución" si las dos palabras son iguales.

```
def aprender_con_reemplazo(oracion, buscar):
  recordar_pal = sobre_ti
  for palabra in oracion.split():
      if buscar in recordar_pal and buscar != palabra:  # <-- Condicion añadida
        recordar_pal[palabra] = recordar_pal[buscar]
        del recordar_pal[buscar]
      if palabra not in recordar_pal:
         recordar_pal[palabra] = {}
      recordar_pal = recordar_pal[palabra]
```

### Tests

Las siguientes pruebas muestran que ahora todo va bien (espero!)

```
sobre_ti={}
aprender("Yo soy Lola aprendiendo python")
aprender("Yo soy Lola en Stack Overflow")
aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo soy Lola experimentando", "Lola")
```

Produce:

```
{'Yo': {'soy': {'Lola': {'aprendiendo': {'python': {}},
                         'en': {'Stack': {'Overflow': {}}},
                         'experimentando': {}}}}}
```

Y también funciona con la raíz del árbol:

```
sobre_ti={}
aprender("Yo soy Lola que tal")
aprender("Yo soy Maria hola")
aprender_con_reemplazo("Yo soy Carlos", "Yo")
```

Resultado:

```
{'Yo': {'soy': {'Carlos': {},
                'Lola': {'que': {'tal': {}}},
                'Maria': {'hola': {}}}}}
```

Comment: Eres un genio, jamás pensé que ese seria el problema, estoy leyendo el código una y otra vez para grabarme bien su funcionamiento,  Abulafia gracias a ti estoy aprendiendo mucho, espero que con el tiempo no moleste tanto y pueda avanzar sin interferencias.

Comment: @Lolita El código, aunque de pocas líneas, es difícil de entender porque trabaja sobre una estructura de datos cambiante. Es normal que te cueste. Creo que te puede ayudar a visualizar su funcionamiento un sitio como [PythonTutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) que muestra gráficamente la evolución de los datos paso a paso a medida que tu código los va manipulando

Comment: Gracias! La usare.